# Problem formating date in datepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got a datepicker in a modal and I need to send this date to another, the problem is that when i see the console this date is not getting format as I want.

Here is the javascript that create the datepicker (Bootstrap datepicker):

```
$( function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
```

this is the script that is getting the value of the datepicker

```
$(document).on('click','.btnDesvincular', function(){
  $('#modalDes').appendTo("body").modal('show');
  var badge2 = $(this).attr('data-id');

  $('[type="text"]').change(function() {
    var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val(); //Here im triying to format de date

    console.clear();
    console.log(date);
  });    
});
```

and here is the HTML

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <p>Fecha: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p> 
</div>
```

and this is the other problem, the console give me a duplicate answer, I would appreciate any help

`08/08/2019
08/08/2019`

Comment: is it jQuery-ui datepicker?

Comment: no, is a bootstrap datepicker

Comment: Ok, I made an [edit] on your question and added a snippet to reproduce your code, please check if this reproduces what you said

Comment: unfortunaly is not what i said,i will try to explain me better, i want formating the date : yy-mm-dd, when i put this line in the jquery
var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' }).val();
the date is still like 08/07/2019 by example, i need show year-month-day separated by -

Comment: ok, I understood that, I'm only asking you to add a [mcve] as a snippet, I added it to the question, I just want to know if the snippet is reproducing your actual code (it's not to an answer to the qustion)

Comment: yes the snipet is fine, i take out the button btnDesnvincular because that is not the problem, like i said the snipet is fine, thank you very much, my problem is basically the date formating

Comment: But with your current edit, you removed the snippet functionality... turning it in a non reproducible example... But anyway, I don't know bootstrap datepicker, I'm used to jquery's one, sorry... let's wait for someone help

Comment: Save yourself the time and use [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/). There are lots of format options available

Comment: dont worry,i was triying every internet solution and nothing fixed my problem, now i clear my cache and is working, i add data-date-format="yyyy-mm-dd"  to my input